# Find number of tournament participants

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math

The all-play-all chess tournament was played by masters, who were 75% of the players, and grandmasters. Masters scored 20% more points than Grandmasters. How many participants were there?

I tried to figure out this puzzle by creating system of equations. I denoted number of grandmasters as $n$, then there are $3n$ masters. Let grandmasters have $5k$ points, then masters have $6k$. Let the grandmasters and masters be vertices of some graph, and edges will be chess games. Sum score of every game is 1.
Therefore, number of edges is sum score of all players: $$\frac{4n(4n-1)}{2} = 11k$$
What should I do next? I tried to create more equations but it didn't come out well. BTW, the answer is 12, as said in my Math problem book.

Comment: Is this even possible? Imagine there are $20$ participants, and $5$ of them are grandmasters. The $15$ masters get $240$ points, while the grandmasters have $200$. Now just double the amount of participants: everything will still be ok. So I wonder if you're not missing some condition.

Comment: @Dominique Not everything gets preserved when doubling, because everyone plays *everyone except for themselves*. So in your example, each grandmaster plays $\frac45$ of the grandmasters; if we double, each grandmaster playes $\frac9{10}$ of the grandmasters.

Comment: @Dominique 1. In a tournament of 20 participants there are $190$ points on stake. How did you get $440$? 2. If you double the roster, the number of points _does not_ double.

Comment: Hint: LHS must be divisible by $11$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an upper limit on the number of participants, for the following reason.

The masters score at least $\binom{3n}{2}$ points, because there are that many games played between two masters. Correspondingly, the grandmasters score at most $\binom n2 + n \cdot 3n$ points, because that's how many games a grandmaster participates in. The "20% more points" condition gives us the inequality $$\binom{3n}{2} \le (\text{masters' points}) = \frac65 (\text{grandmasters' points}) \le \frac65 \left(\binom n2 + 3n^2\right).$$
Now we simplify the inequality $$\binom{3n}{2} - \frac65\left(\binom n2 + 3n^2\right) \le 0$$ to the inequality $$\frac{3}{10}n^2 - \frac9{10} n \le 0,$$ which holds only for $0 \le n \le 3$.

Furthermore, the equation $\binom{4n}{2} = 11k$ already present in the question implies that $\binom{4n}{2}$ is divisible by $11$. In our range, this is only true for $n=0$ and $n=3$.

If we assume that "actually, there were no participants, and so the conditions are all satisfied vacuously" is an unacceptable answer, then the only possible outcome is $n=3$ grandmasters and $3n=9$ masters.

It's worth noting that at this extreme range of our earlier inequality, we can deduce a lot about the outcome of the games. Every single master-vs.-grandmaster game must have resulted in a grandmaster win! This way, the $9$ masters only win the $\binom 92 = 36$ games between each other, while the $3$ grandmasters win the $3$ games between each other and all $27$ games they play against the masters: $30$ in total.

Comment: "we can deduce what the outcomes of all the games were." Well, not quite, e.g., you can't tell whether each grandmaster had one win and one loss against her fellow grandmasters, or whether one grandmaster won both her games against her fellows, while another lost both of hers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You're right, and similarly we don't know what's going on with the masters. What I should have said is that we can deduce that every master loses to every grandmaster.